# Data Driven Design in native C++

Tags: c++, xml

So I am writing a game engine that utilizes data driven design to instantiate various actors from xml files.  I recently finished coding the event management system and everything fires off the events and the handlers catch them correctly.  No easy task considering I used member function pointers and templates.  The issue I am having now is that I would like to be able to do something like this in the xml file:

```
<InputComponent>
   <Event  EventName="GainedFocus" OnEvent="Initialize"/>
</InputComponent>
```

The problem should be pretty obvious. C++ has no form of reflection and therefore cannot, as far as I know, get the address for the Initialize function from the string "Initialize".  This means that for slightly different input components I have derive from the class and register the events specific to that instance and add the functions.  Also, it should be known that this is different than the way I am handling typical input:

```
<InputComponent>
   <Mapping Type="MousePress" Button=1 Command="RotateCamera"/>
</InputComponent>
```

In this instance mapping is an element specific to input components and commands are themselves objects that are created with a factory.  I cannot really do this with generic events though.  Commands are specific items that perform the exact same operations on different objects whereas objects or components themselves often need to handle individual events differently.  Has anyone done anything like this before?  Genuinely curious as to how someone could go about doing something like this so that events that need to be registered to an object dont have to be hard coded into the class itself.

EDIT: Let me word it this way.  Different INSTANCES of the same type of components need to react differently to events.  This will be application specific and as such should be separate from the engine code (I shouldn't have to modify the components).  The user should be able to supply functions that can then be called upon reaction to an event.  Both the function and event should be able to be bound in XML.  I am starting to think this might just be impossible in unmanaged C++ because there is no form of metadata to look up the functions supplied by the user based on a string of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map that associates strings with function pointers.
Or if the function signatures differ you can use a Factory pattern with an if-else-if ladder.

**Edit 1: Example**

```
// Typedef for event functions
typedef void (*Event_Function_Pointer)(const Event& e);

typedef std::map<std::string, Event_Function_Pointer> Event_Function_Container;

//...
Event_Function_Container events;
events["Gained Focus"] = Initialize;
```

There's also an option of having lookup table since the text and the function pointers are constant data:

```
struct Event_Function_Entry
{
  char * const * event_name;
  Event_Function_Pointer event_function;
};

Event_Function_Entry events[] =
{
  {"Gained Focus", Initialize},
};
```

Comment: Yeah, the whole issue I think arises from the fact that my delegates are done through templates that use member function pointers which does mean the actual component classes themselves have to change to add event handlers.  Otherwise I could just use generic function pointers and add them to a tree like you said.  The only way I can think to do it with member function pointers is to have generic event handler classes contained withing the component.  This way I wouldn't have to change the components themselves but could write versions of theses classes and plug em in where they are needed.

Comment: Also the issue is that I cannot find the actual entry point for the Initialize function from its string representation in xml without some sort of reflection.  If I could do that, then using a dynamic data structure to store and execute based on event Id would be simple.  I am wondering how to take the string "Initialize" in XML and have my XML parsing code create a delegate that actually finds the entry point to a function with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your components could all inherit from a same base, that provindes the interface for basic operations that your commands will invoque:

```
class Component {
public:  
    virtual void initialize(); 
    virtual void rotate(int x, int y); 
    ...
};

class Monster : public Component {
   virtual void initialize();   // concrete implementation for a Monster 
   virtual void rotate(int x, int y); 
};
```

You may then consider the **["command" design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)**.  The general idea would be:

```
class Command {   // generic interface for commands
    Component *receiver;  
public: 
    Command(Component *receiver);  
    virtual ~Command(); 
    virtual void execute();     

};

class InitializeCommand : Command {  // a specific command
public: 
    InitializeCommand (Component *receiver /* + additional command specific parameters */); // specific constructor with all needed parameters
    void execute() { 
         // use the parameters and do the common operations 
         receiver->initialize();   // polymorphically call the object operations 
         // ...
         }
};
```

The rest depends of your global design.

You could for example design a factory that would create the commands based on the events that are processed and execute these:

```
if (event==...) {
    // todo: find object pointed to by the object
    Command c = myfactory_for_event (object, parameters); 
    c.execute(); 
}
```

Of if your xml file is meant to configure an object, then you read the file, create specific commands, and store them in an event map that associates an event name to a concrete command:

```
map<string,Command*> commands;
```

In this case, the event processing would be something like:

```
myobject["initialize"]->execute();
```

Comment: I have the commands and command factory all figured out.  The problem is that, for example input components may need to react differently for the same events.  For example I may want to disable some when they lose focus while others need to stay enabled when they lose focus. To facilitate this, I don't want to alter the InputComponent class every single time I need it to react differently to an event.  I just wanna supply a string in xml, and function in c++ and have it bind to that function.  Kindof like the way WPF does it.  Click="OnCick" then you just write the OnClick function and viola.

Answer (score 0):

So no one knows if there is any way to do this? Obviously there are hack ways.  Multiple integration, multiple factories etc.  I could ONLY have responses to events done as Command objects but that seems like a weird solution...because there is no runtime information available I have to encapsulate each INDIVIDUAL function in its own class..waste of memory if you ask me...Just realized how weird that sounds. Basically what I meant is for each funtion I wanted to map to an event I would have to create an entire new class (same as the command pattern I am already using to map keys).  Would be much easier if I could just provide a function address instead of allocating and deallocating memory for ever individual action but no one seems to have an answer.